# auditd: Difference between watch and syscall

Tags: auditd

There appear to be two ways of specifying an auditd rule to watch a given file or folder. The first uses `-a`

```
-a exit,always -F dir=/path/to/file -F perm=wa -F success=1
```

And the second uses `-w`

```
-w /path/to/file -p wa
```

Aside from one being obviously shorter, the two appear to have the same effect. Is there some subtle difference between them I need to understand?

Comment: Did you read the documentation on `-w` ?

Comment: If you mean the `man` page, yes. It's quite short. It just says `-w` audits "access" to the files, while `-a` audits system calls. Is there more thorough documentation elsewhere?

Comment: You need to look at the auditctl man page.

Comment: That appears to say that they are the same.

Comment: You missed this bit `The -w form of writing watches  is  for  backwards compatibility...`